# How to disable the cache for header.phtml in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to use rand() php function in header.phml but if Magento cache is enabled then rand() function display old random value, but if the cache is disabled then it is working fine. so please give me the suggestion.

Comment: Use Ajax for that.

Comment: Did you overrided the layout file of xml?

Comment: No I did not overrided the layout

Comment: @DhirendrasinhDRC my answer here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/202703/33057

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to override that block file and add `cachable = "false"` in your layout file it will work. For example check below, this will disable the cache for that particular part even the cache enabled in backend.

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Currency" name="currency" template="Vendor_Module::currency.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Thank you :)
It's working fine in my case.

Comment: @jeeva make cachable = "false" is making whole page  not particular block & you are adding in header so whole site is not cacheable

Comment: Only header block is not cacheable right? We are adding that for particular block how the whole site won't work..If any thing i said wrong means  please tell me your suggestion

Comment: Do not use this! As Yogesh said you will lose caching for every page on your site!

Comment: Thank you for all suggestions. 
Can you give me proper way for this because I new in magento 2.