# Checkout session not work in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, full-page-cache, checkoutsession

I have used `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` for get quote id and store my custom value in this. but its return every time empty session. `when FPC on or customer not logged in.`

I have found out some solution but no luck with this. My block is placed in header section so its not good to used `cacheable="false"`. Because its turn off all my pages cache.

Any other solution?

**Edited**

```
$checkoutSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
$resultPageFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory');
$quoteId = $checkoutSession->getQuoteId();
```

Comment: I will give you an Ajax sample later tonight.

Comment: did you check to ensure that you are using https to browse the portal and the checkout pages as well? Something session mismatch issue happens due to http and https in URLs

Comment: i am work on local

Comment: Can you specify, your code which you try to get quote id from session.

Comment: check updated question

Comment: @AjayPatel see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should not try to use `cacheable="false"` in your header because it will disable cache all pages. Use the Ajax way.

For example,

Because I cannot find a better way (it should be layout xml) to set the template for Html header block. So, I tried to override it.

**app/code/Vendor/Theme/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header"
                type="Vendor\Theme\Block\Html\Header" />
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Theme/Block/Html/Header.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Theme\Block\Html;

class Header extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header
{
    /**
     * Current template name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'Vendor_Theme::html/header.phtml';

}
```

**app/code/Vendor/Theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml**

Add these code lines:

```
.......
<li class="show-random-number"
    data-mage-init='{"Vendor_Theme/js/header/radom": {"ajaxUrl":
    "<?php echo $block->getUrl('vendor_theme/ajax/random')?>"}}'>
</li>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Theme/view/frontend/web/js/header/radom.js**

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * @param {String} url
     * @param {*} element
     */
    function processData(url, element) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (res) {
            $(element).html("Random value: " + res.random);
        }).complete(function () {

        });
    }

    return function (config, element) {
        processData(config.ajaxUrl, element);
    };
});
```

**app/code/Vendor/Theme/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="vendor_theme" frontName="vendor_theme">
            <module name="Vendor_Theme" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Theme/Controller/Ajax/Random.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Theme\Controller\Ajax;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

class Random extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var JsonFactory
     */
    protected $jsonFactory;

    /**
     * Random constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param JsonFactory $jsonFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        JsonFactory $jsonFactory
    ) {
        $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $response = [
            'errors' => false,
            'random' => rand()
        ];

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw $resultRaw */
        $resultJson = $this->jsonFactory->create();
        return $resultJson->setData($response);
    }
}
```

Remember to create `module.xml` and `registration.php`. Clear your Magento Cache. We can see the result.

[image]

Comment: yea as i mention its disable all pages caches

Comment: i am waiting for your sollution

Comment: Sure! Will do but I need to go home :)

Comment: Sorry but i want to get updated value from checkout session

Comment: I think it's better you should build your own logic in the controller. You can inject `Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` to the constructor.

Comment: i have already try to get value from controller but no luck :(

Comment: Make sure your quote object exists or not. I'm pretty sure it will work.

Comment: let me check with this

Comment: If having new issues, you can update your question.

Comment: i have check this but not work, for your help up vote., finally i got solution to change build in cache to varnish cache and its work fine